# Should the scroll wheel zoom be disabled for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am working on a web application using Google Maps. Occasionally, when one zooms using the scroll wheel, an overlay (KML data) is not re-sized correctly. Except for using the scroll wheel, I have not been able to consistently reproduce this behavior.

A Google search on Google Maps and scroll wheel is returning several items on disabling zoom for the scroll wheel.

Some related map settings:

```
//Map Functionality 
map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
map.enableContinuousZoom();
```

Is the mouse wheel zoom so erratic that one should disable as a *best practice*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to repeat this behavior consistently. Once the map loaded, use the scroll wheel and aggressively zoom in. And do mean aggressively. If I zoom in at a moderate or slow pace there's no problem.

I commented out `map.enableContinuousZoom();` and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I found related to this (for me anyway) was in Chrome (Windows 7) and compatibility with a Logitech extension for Chrome : `Logitech Flow Scroll 4.0.33`.

As soon as I disabled the extension, using the scroll wheel to zoom in/out started working correctly.